# Add percentage to Bokeh Donut Chart

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am using Bokeh Donut charts to create pie charts.  I am using the hover tool to show the raw size and category of each slice of the pie on mouse over.  I would also like the hover tool to show the percent of the whole of each slice.

Is this possible?  My understanding is that there is currently an open pull request focused on building the capability to add arbitrary additional info to the hover tool, but is there any sort of current work around that would allow me to achieve this?  I've been trying to experiment with ways to manually add columns to the hover tool data source (ColumnDataSource?) with no success yet.  Currently the `Percentage` tooltip for the hover just comes up `???`.

```
#limit data 
tension = rrima.loc[:,['community_tension','tension_pct']]

#analysis of community tensions
tensions = Donut(tension,label='community_tension',values='community_tension',agg='count',
                 plot_height=plot_height,plot_width=plot_width,title='Reported Community Tensions')


hover = HoverTool(point_policy='follow_mouse')
hover.tooltips = [('Survey Responses','@values'),('Percentage','@tension_pct'),('Community Tensions','@community_tension')]
tensions.add_tools(hover)
```

Answer (score 0):

The old `bokeh.charts` API, including `Donut` was deprecated and completely removed last year. You can accomplish this with the stable `bokeh.plotting` API, however. Here is a complete example using Bokeh 0.13:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.palettes import Category20c
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

# Some example data
x = Counter({ 'United States': 157, 'United Kingdom': 93, 'Japan': 89, 'China': 63,
              'Germany': 44, 'India': 42, 'Italy': 40, 'Australia': 35, 'Brazil': 32,
              'France': 31, 'Taiwan': 31, 'Spain': 29 })
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(x), orient='index').reset_index().rename(index=str, columns={0:'value', 'index':'country'})
data['percent'] = data['value'] / sum(x.values()) * 100
data['angle'] = data['value'] / sum(x.values()) * 2*pi
data['color'] = Category20c[len(x)]

p = figure(plot_height=350, tooltips="@country: @percent{0.2f} %")

p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.4,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='country', source=data)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: "from bokeh.io import, show" type: should be from "bokeh.io import show" (remove 
the extra ",")